# How can I capture a hash to Object in functional JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hash, functional-programming

I'm writing a piece of code in JavaScript for modern browser. I'm not using lodash or underscore as we want to keep the library as small as possible.

For example,

If the url comes like this. `http://something.com/#hash=value`
And the app is configured to capture key `hash` then the result would be this. Nothing fancy. I was just wondering if there's a better way or simple way to do this.

```
{
 'hash': 'value'
}
```

The code

```
var config = Object.assign({}, {
    capturedHashParams: ['hash']
});

var hashValue = '#hash=value1'.substr(1);

var capturedHashParams = {};
if (config.capturedHashParams && Array.isArray(config.capturedHashParams)) {
  var splitedHash = hashValue.split('=');
  if (splitedHash.length > 0) {
    var key = splitedHash[0] || '';
    var value = splitedHash[1] || '';
    if (key && value) {
      config.capturedHashParams.forEach(function(hp) {
        if (hp.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
          capturedHashParams[key] = value;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(capturedHashParams);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c92p0rfm/2/

Comment: Yes, as simple as using `window.location.hash`

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I need to transform them to be an Object instead of just a string.

Comment: Them? Meaning multiple hashes in the URL?

Comment: Only one hash but in multiple values. #hash=value&hash1=value1

Comment: Maybe something like this? `var capturedHashParams={};window.location.hash.substring(1).split("&").forEach(function(hashes) {var hashvalue=hashes.split("=");capturedHashParams[hashvalue[0]]=hashvalue[1];});;` Short and simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. It appears that you want to extract key/value pairs from an url hash and return as a JavaScript object. I am bit uncertain about whether you want to extract all key/value pairs or only those provided in a config object. I am also a bit uncertain as to whether you want a solution within a strict functional programming paradigm, or just a plain solution with a small code footprint. I will assume the latter.

A straightforward approach to capture all key/value pairs:

```js
var url = 'http://something.com/#hash=value&anotherHash=value';

//extract key=value pairs from url
var params = url.split('#').pop().split('&');

//assign to data object
for(var data = {}, i = 0, temp; i < params.length; i++){
  // extract array [key, value]
  temp = params[i].split('=');
  // assign to data object
  data[temp[0]] = temp[1];
}

console.log(data);
```

A more compact solution to do the same with `.reduce()`:

```js
var url = 'http://something.com/#hash=value&anotherHash=value';

var data = url
 .split('#')
 .pop()
 .split('&')
 .reduce(function(obj, keyval){
   keyval = keyval.split('=');
   obj[keyval[0]] = keyval[1];
   return obj;
 }, {});

console.log(data)
```

If you want to configure which keys to extract:

```js
var url = 'http://something.com/#hash=value&anotherHash=value&notThisHash=value';

//config object
var keysToCapture = [
  'hash',
  'anotherHash'
];

var data = url
 .split('#')
 .pop()
 .split('&')
 .reduce(function(obj, keyval){
   keyval = keyval.split('=');
   if(keysToCapture.indexOf(keyval[0]) > -1){
     obj[keyval[0]] = keyval[1];
   }
   return obj;
 }, {});

console.log(data)
```

Which you could capture in a reusable function like this:

```js
function extractParamsObject(url, keysToCapture){
  return url
   .split('#')
   .pop() //hash/fragment: everything after the last #
   .split('&')
   .reduce(function(obj, keyval){
     keyval = keyval.split('=');
     if(keysToCapture.indexOf(keyval[0]) > -1){
       obj[keyval[0]] = keyval[1];
     }
     return obj;
   }, {});
}

console.log(extractParamsObject(
  'http://something.com/#hash=value&anotherHash=value&notThisHash=value',
  ['hash', 'anotherHash']
));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are watching for something like this:

```
var output = [];
var hashString = window.location.hash;
var hashArray = hash.split('&');

for(var index = 0; index < hashArray.length; index++){
  var text = hashArray[index];
  var tempArray= text.split('=');
  var object = {
    id: tempArray[0],
    value: tempArray[1]
  };
  output[index] = object;
}
```

now output looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "hash",
    value: "value"
  }
]
```